# Passing pointer of vector of objects as arguments but a lot more different

Tags: c++, function, class, object, vector

This question does look like a copy and paste of an old one (which it sort of is) but I assure you the situation is a lot more different and very hard to explain so please hear me out before you murder my miniscule reputation.

I am having issues with taking vectors holding objects into function parameters, then scanning them and putting a specific object into another function's parameters which would then use all the values of that specific object.

For instance if there were a player class and enemy class:

```
class player{
public:
int id;
string name;
};

class enemy{
public:
int eid;
string name;
};
```

And there were some objects of those classes stored in their own vectors:

```
player example;
example.id = 1;
example.name = "example";

enemy badEnemy;
badEnemy.eid = 1;
badEnemy.name = "badEnemy";

vector<player> allPlayers;
vector<enemy> allEnemys; //I know the spellings wrong but am to reluctant to change it
allPlayers.push_back(example);
allEnemys.push_back(badEnemy);
```

And then there was a function that printed out the objects names:

```
    int fightEnemy(player player, enemy enemy) {
    cout << player.name << endl;
    cout << enemy.name << endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

After that there would be a function that scans for specific objects in the vector and inserts them into the `fightEnemy` function

```
int enemyComboCheck(int id1, int id2, vector<Player>* allPlayers, vector<enemy>* allEnemys){
  int iteratorForPlayer = 0;
  id1 -= 1;
  id2 -= 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < 18; ++i){
    if(id1 == allPayers[iteratorForPlayer].id && id2 == allEnemys[i].id) fightEnemy(allPlayers[iteratorForPlayer], allEnemys[i]);
//how do I pass the scanned object into the other function
      }
      return 0;
}
```

I guess my main question is how do I pass the scanned object into the other function through a vector? Would I have to use a vector in the other function?

Sorry for all the bad formatting, anyways thanks!

Comment: Why 18 in the loop?

Comment: @Donnie It was for the program I was having trouble with, there were 18 enemies and 5 players

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass it exactly the same way you're referencing them in your `if` statement.

`fightEnemy(allPlayers[iteratorForPlayer], allEnemies[i]);`

And fix the spelling.  That's what global find and replace is for.

I would suggest changing the signature of `fightEnemy` to take references so you don't have to copy objects, and you can change things like hitpoints if you need to.  This will not change the way you call it:

`int fightEnemy(player &player, enemy &enemy)`

Comment: I added all that and there aren't any errors, but the issue now is that fightEnemy won't show up in the console.